# How to initialize the size of an array

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    char s1[]={0};
    char s2[]={0};
    scanf("%s",s1);
    scanf("%s",s2);
    printf("%s",s2);
}
```

My question：
When type  some letter into S1 and S2 ,S2 will copy my S1.
Why is this problem and can you initialize an array without identifying its size.

Comment: You did initialize its size (to 1).

Comment: You only provide memory to hold 1 character in each array. That is too small to hold any string. It can only hold the terminating 0 byte. This means you mustn't pass the address of these arrays to `scanf`.

Comment: You are reading a string into an array of length 1. Use `-fsanitize=address -g` as compiler options to detect memory problems.

Comment: You want `char s1[100]={0};` etc. Now `s1` cn contain strings up to a length of 99. `char s1[100]={0};` gives the array a ssize of 1. This shoukld be covered in your learrning material in the chapter dealing with arrays and strings

Answer (score 1):

The `[]` means that the compiler will pick the size after the amount of items provided in the initializer list. In this case you have one item `0` so the arrays get size one. You cannot change the size afterwards. Therefore your code has undefined behavior bugs - you allocated too little memory and the `scanf` calls will write out-of-bounds of the arrays.

In case you need to change an array size in run-time, you need to either use dynamic memory allocation with `malloc` or use a variable-length array (VLA).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the size of an array at run time too by declaring it in a variable and then getting it as a input using scanf.

But in your program you have already declared the array so the size of array is also fixed as 1.

Comment: Eh? scanf does not do runtime allocation.

Comment: The user can give the size of array for taking input from the user we use scanf.